# How to save a CR2/NEF/RAW image to album in camera roll (IOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10

I have a CR2 image(photoed by Canon DSLR) saved in sandbox, and I wanna add it to camera roll. So I use method below, but it cause error with no description. How to save CR2 to camera roll? Thanks a lot!

```
[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
    // Request creating an asset from the image.
    PHAssetChangeRequest *createAssetRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromImageAtFileURL:[NSURL URLWithString:localPath]];
    // Request editing the album.
    PHFetchResult<PHAssetCollection *> *albumList = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeSmartAlbumUserLibrary options:nil];
    PHAssetCollection *album;
    for(PHAssetCollection *am in albumList){
        if([am.localizedTitle isEqualToString:ALBUMN]){
            album = am;
        }
    }
    PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest *albumChangeRequest = [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest changeRequestForAssetCollection:album];
    // Get a placeholder for the new asset and add it to the album editing request.
    PHObjectPlaceholder *assetPlaceholder = [createAssetRequest placeholderForCreatedAsset];
    [albumChangeRequest addAssets:@[assetPlaceholder]];
    } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"-=-=-=-Finished adding asset. %@", (success ? @"Success" : error));
    }];
```

output messate:ImageIO: PluginForUTType:316: file format 'com.canon.cr2-raw-image' doesn't support writing